# MVC4 WebAPI filters: any way to stub Filter.Order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, action-filter

I have two filters added to a WebAPI controller:

```
[FooFilter]
[BarFilter]
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> GetSomething()
{
    ...
```

Unfortunately, they are being executed in random order.

For the MVC stack, [there's the `Order` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filter.order%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) where one could just do

```
[FooFilter(Order = 1)]
[BarFilter(Order = 2)]
public IQueryable<SomeEntity> GetSomething()
{
    ...
```

There's [an article on StrathWeb](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/control-the-execution-order-of-your-filters-in-asp-net-web-api/) about adding `Order` support to WebAPI, which seems outdated and just won't compile for me.

Do the C# wizards of SO have any advice on how to implement/stub the `Order` attribute for WebAPI?

Comment: There's mention of this here too: http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147201-asp-net-web-api/suggestions/3346720-execution-order-of-mvc4-webapi-action-filters

Comment: The sample code from the linked article compiles and works fine. Just make sure that you are using the right `IFilterProvider` because MVC and Wep.API has their own. What you need is the `System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider`. Here is the relevant experts form my CustomFilterProvider.cs file `using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution from the article works fine and compiles.

Just make sure you use the correct namespaces, since some of the classes have the same name under `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.Http` namespaces.

These are the fully qualified names you should be referencing:

```
System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilter
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterScope
System.Web.Http.Filters.FilterInfo
System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider
```

Also, remember that once implemented, your filters need to start inheriting from `BaseActionFilterAttribute` instead of the original `ActionFilterAttribute` (that's the only way you'd get the `Position` property).