# ExceptionFilter stack trace in synchronous action scenario

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a simple synchronous action in a Controller that throws an exception like so :

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("whatever");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "response");
    }
}
```

I also have an ExceptionFilterAttribute to get a hold of exceptions that occur in the application

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionContext)
    {
        var ex = actionContext.Exception;
        // Log ex, etc.
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in that I do get a hold of the exception in `MyExceptionFilterAttribute`. The problem is the stack trace. Here is what it looks like :

```
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

So my question : How do I get the "real" stack trace (that would point to the method in the controller where the exception occured) ?

More generally, because clearly there is something I don't understand, where is the async coming from in this scenario ? Does the web api automatically create an async task when it hits a controller method ?

I am using Web API v2.0 ([packages v5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.0.0)) and cannot upgrade to more recent versions (complicated story).

More info : I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977142/) so I tried inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute instead of ExceptionFilterAttribute but the stack trace already looked like the above one when the `ActionFilterAttribute` was getting hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to not upgrade Web API packages, then you best option is probably to avoid using `ActionFilters` for handling exceptions at all.

A better (and global) approach would be to create an `ExceptionHandler` to replace the default implementation inside the Web API configuration:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Exception;

        //log exception, do stuff

        context.Result = new InternalServerErrorResult(context.Request);
    }

    public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        bool shouldHandle;

        //logic to check if you should handle the exception or not

        return shouldHandle;
    }
}
```

And inside `WebApiConfig.cs` (assuming `config` is your `HttpConfiguration` object):

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyExceptionHandler());
```

If you, instead, only want to log the exception (and not handling it in some way), then you could implement an `ExceptionLogger` in a similar way:

```
public class MyExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        MyLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, context.Exception, "some message");
    }
}
```

And again:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new MyExceptionLogger());
```

Comment: Thank you Federico, I did not know about the IExceptionHandler interface. The IExceptionLogger would be even better but it unfortunately came about in 5.1.2 (Web API 2.1). Still, this solution mostly works for me. Do you have any idea where the async stuff comes from in my example though ?

Comment: I believe this happens because every action filter implements the `IActionFilter` interface, which [only declares `ExecuteActionFilterAsync`](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/IActionFilter.cs#11). `ActionFilterAttribute` itself [calls the synchronous methods inside the asynchronous ones](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs), and thus everything is is wrapped inside a `Task`.

Comment: Yup, makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much for your help!