# ASP.NET Web API Global Exception Handling - Stack Trace readability

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an ASP.Net Web API Project (.Net Framework 4.7.1)

I'm trying to use ExceptionLogger to handle exceptions globally and log them

My implementation looks like this :

```
public class MyExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(context.Exception);
    }
}
```

I subscribed it into the WebApiConfig.cs like this :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Configuration et services API Web
    config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new MyExceptionLogger());

    [...]
}
```

It catches well the uncaught exceptions from the controllers but the stack trace seems too verbose :

```
   at WebApplication.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in [...]\source\repos\WebApplication\WebApplication\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 15
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

The part from "**--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---**" makes the stack trace heavy and not easilly readable
It seems to be related to some async code, but my controller does not have any async code :

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        throw new Exception("Test");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Is there any way to have a "more readable" stack trace ?

I checked this thread but none of the explained solutions worked on my project :
[ExceptionFilter stack trace in synchronous action scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039046/exceptionfilter-stack-trace-in-synchronous-action-scenario)

Answer (score 0):

Every `Exception` might have an `InnerException` so you need to check `InnerException` as well.

```
while(exception != null)
{
   Console.Error.WriteLine(exception);
   if(exception.InnerException != null)
      exception = exception.InnerException;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Ben Adams has recently developed a package which could make exception more readable:
[image]
https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier

Comment: Unfortunately InnerException is NULL
Furthermore I feel uncomfortable to use an extension for something that should be native

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackTrace class from System.Diagnostic and then you can write your exceptions to somewhere else. This class helps you to read your stackTrace with fileNames and Line Numbers

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx